Install plugins in neovim
I’m new in nvim I want to install typescript-language-service on nvim But can I not do that Please see all my configs and say me What should I do

my configs/lspconfig.lua
-- EXAMPLE 
local configs = require("configs.lspconfig")

local on_attach = configs.on_attach
local on_init = configs.on_init
local capabilities = configs.capabilities

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local servers = { "html", "cssls", "clangd"}

for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_init = on_init,
    on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end

  --- typescript
lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}


my custom/chadrc.lua :
local M = {}

M.ui = {
    theme = "onedark",

    -- hl_override = {
    --  Comment = { italic = true },
    --  ["@comment"] = { italic = true },
    -- },
}
M.plugins = "custom.plugins"

return M


my custom/plugins.lua :
local plugins = {
   {
   "williamboman/mason.nvim",
   opts = {
      ensure_installed = {
        "lua-language-server",
        "typescript-language-server",
        "html-lsp",
        "prettier",
        "stylua"
      },
    },
  },
-- In order to modify the `lspconfig` configuration:
{
  "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
   config = function()
      require("configs.lspconfig").defaults()
      require "configs.lspconfig"
   end,
},

}

return plugins

My Error Text in ':MasonInstallAll' When I want to install Manual typescript-language-service:
 typescript-language-server ▼ Displaying full log Initialized npm root. Installing npm package typescript-language-server@4.3.3… spawn: npm failed with exit code 1 and signal 0.

I installed and removed manytime nvchad. But can I not do that. my nvim version is 10 My nvchad version is 2.5


You'd normally install typescript-language-server from a JavaScript package manager such as Npm, Yarn, Pnpm...:
npm install -g typescript-language-server

and not via your editor (nvim) or IDE.
If that command doesn't work, you first need to install the package manager itself:
sudo apt install npm


Bro, I want to have a JavaScript intellisense in neovim . I did this command, but I can not install typescript-language-server to use JavaScript intellisense in nvim

I did this command, but I can not install typescript-language-server to use JavaScript intellisense in nvim Why? Was there an error? If typescript-language-server is installed then nvim (if properly configured) and any other editor with support for it will use it... You seem to be setting it up in lspconfig.lua so the problem is the language server itself is not installed.
